# TeamCity - Create Project From URL

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

I can't seem to create a project from a url when using TeamCity. I am hosting my code on bitbucket using mercurial. When I enter the repository URL, I get this error:

> Cannot create a project using the specified URL. The URL is not
>   recognized.

My url looks like this:

```
https://logeyg@bitbucket.org/logeyg/tracs-enhancements
```

And I am of course supplying a username and password. I have tried removing the '`logeyg@`' but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try SSH URL? What exact version of TC do you use?

There were some fixes in 9.0.2 version (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-39730), maybe it is also for BitBucket.

Btw. I've just tried with internal Git repo and it works fine with both HTTPS and SSH protocols. Maybe there is a problem with BitBucket itself.

Comment: yup, I'm using the latest (9.0.4), tried ssh as well

Comment: Unfortunately, my company's TC is behind a proxy so I cannot try with BitBucket to test it...

Answer (score 0):

There is a ticket suggi(https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-48788) suggesting mercurial may not be installed.

Ensure mercurial is installed (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/)

Try https://bitbucket.org/logeyg/tracs-enhancements/src without the username and add /src

Check the Admin-> Diagnostics -> Server Logs -> teamcity-vcs 
This will provide more info eg. invalid credentials, hg not installed.

Answer (score -1):

If your using bitbucket. Use the clone project URL. Once you do that the "create project URL" in TC will auto detect everything.  I user Https and not ssh. Thanks